# How does one “toast someone” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, verbes

In English, there is a very specific meaning of the word "toast"; when used as a transitive verb, it means that you raise glasses in celebration of someone or something, eg.:

> Let's toast the winner of the race!

It can also be used as a noun to refer to the act itself:

> I propose a toast, to the winner of the race!

Is there an equivalent French way to express this notion?

I came across the verb ‘*trinquer*’, which apparently means ‘to clink glasses’.  This seems to have no equivalent in English; would one perhaps use it to mean ‘toast’ in this sense?

Comment: I'd really appreciate if someone could address the 'trinquer' verb in an answer.  I'm confused as to when you would use it.

Comment: Quelle tristesse de ne pas avoir un verbe pour "trinquer".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On utilise et on entend en français « levons notre verre » suivi de la raison de la célébration, pour le « toast ».

Maintenant, « portons un toast » est aussi de plus en plus utilisé.

Comme le fait aussi remarquer Laurent en commentaire, il est exact que j'ai aussi entendu l'expression « buvons à (la santé de) [quelqu'un] ». Je la trouve cependant beaucoup moins répandue mais cela peut fort dépendre là encore des différentes régions et habitudes.

Comment: On dit aussi *Buvons à X* ou *Buvons à la santé de X*.

Comment: Exact, réponse mise à jour.

Comment: Ou même une combinaison des deux: _Je lève mon verre à la santé de monsieur Dupont._

Comment: Tout ceci est très verbeux et cérémoniel. L'important, une fois encore, est bel et bien de *boire*. Pour toute occasion qui n'est pas outrancièrement formelle, on se passe donc en général du superflu : "à la tienne", "à la vôtre", "au vainqueur de la course" (sous-entendu à leur santé, ou prospérité, ou qu'importe) suffit amplement comme préambule aux libations.

Comment: Ça pourrait aussi très bien « à autre chose » que « à la santé de », tel qu'au succès ou la réussite ou quelque chose de plus spécifique.

Answer (score 12):

In French, we use the same verb but in slightly different way:

> Porter un toast.
>
> Portons un toast au vainqueur.

We also can use:

> Lever son verre à [un événement].

Answer (score 10):

En français, je ne dirais rien de plus que « Au vainqueur ! » en levant mon verre.

On peut aussi rajouter un verbe, par exemple :

> Buvons à la santé du vainqueur !
>
> Trinquons pour le vainqueur !

« Portons un toast », je ne l'ai entendu que dans des traductions de séries américaines.

Comment: Dans les mauvaises traductions, donc ;)

Comment: ... et donc, comme la vie imite l'art, dans de nombreuses scènes vécues autour de nous, utilisée par des personnes abondamment abreuvées à ladite source. On peut désapprouver, et c'est mon cas, mais il ne faut pas nier la réalité. (bonne réponse cependant, +1)

Answer (score 4):

It's almost another question, but 'trinquer' is effectively 'clinking glasses', and the closest English equivalent is 'cheers', I guess. Though the strict translation of 'cheers' is 'santé': I guess 'trinquer' is what you *do* while you're *saying* 'cheers'.

Comment: Only English speakers use 'sante' as an orphan, all by itself.  A French person would always say 'a votre sante', 'a ta sante', or even more familiarly 'a la votre' or 'a la tienne'.

Comment: @GeorgeM, seems to me that it works in Switzerland though.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this wasn't made clear in any other answer.

Frenchmen (I cannot say for other French-speaking countries) in informal situations usually drink in the honor of an event, rather than of persons directly.

The most common in the case you describe would be:

> À la victoire de Tartanpion !

Which can be preceded by “Je propose que nous trinquions…“ to get everyone's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Trinquer does mean literally to clink your glasses together.  Almost always glasses containing alcohol, you might trinquer with a child's diabolo menthe, but you'd never trinquer a coffee with an adult.

But as always there are extensions of meaning, especially for this very popular pastime.  So you can 'trinquer a --' to seize any occasion to clink glasses, whether you're trinquer a quelque chose like the opening of the exhibition or the election results, or trinquer a quelqu'un like to someone on the occasion of their birthday, retirement etc.  Note that trinquer almost always has a connotation of celebration, even if it's ironic.

And finally it's common to trinquer avec quelqu'un meaning to spend the entire evening with them getting drunk and chewing over the latest events.  You can't trinquer alone, but you could trinquer in consolation, if it's not celebration it should at least imply friendliness.

Answer (score 0):

"trinquer" actually origins from the german verb trinken which means "to drink" ;) Je connais des expressions comme "porter un toast" et "bouvon" ou "sante".